# Katalon/Selenium test failing with IE - "Cannot find the current window; Selenium IE driver connection lost"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, katalon, ie11

I'm finding lately (last few weeks) that automated scripts in Katalon using IE driver are falling over. Failing with message: 
"Cannot find the current window; Selenium IE driver connection lost".

Have also rewritten the test case using Selenium + Java and getting the same result.
Have been through the IE setup previously (ie change registry settings as per Katalon instructions).

any ideas please?
Cheers Dan

Comment: Did you set up IE correctly: https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Internet+Explorer+Configurations ?

Comment: Hi - as per post, all config/registry changes made as per Katalon site setup instructions. Another point to mention is that VM using Windows 7/IE11 does not have issues - multiple users with Win 10/IE11 do get the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on the version of Katalon you are using and the script.  So if you are running a test and the script closes the browser, then the next script needs to open it.  If however the IE window is open and it is not recognizing it then you may need your system to be reconfigured.  Can you please provide more details so we can understand the issue?